# image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); Saving issue

Tags: javascript

How to save `image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` in within the camera div 
onclick camera result automatically getting saved in the first image src line.

[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/kiran9699/pen/eYOPaVL)

Comment: sorry can you reorganise that question so it isn't one long sentence with no punctuation at all making it very difficult to decipher what it is you are actually trying to describe is happening and the question you are actually asking that would be good if you could do that thank you

Comment: https://codepen.io/kiran9699/pen/eYOPaVL- Please find the working codepen

Comment: if its working then there is no issue

Comment: sorry code pen link i working now but I am not able to save the image src in respective image src

Comment: do you get an error in the browser developer tools console when you try to do that?

Comment: I am not getting any error the result( image) is getting saved automatically in the first image src (html) tag .. how can I save this in-camera image src tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing the first img tag. But you need to edit the second one.

Change `let image = document.querySelector("img");` to `let image = document.getElementById("result");`

and

Change `<img src="" alt="" class="image image--hidden" />` to `<img src="" id="result" alt="" class="image image--hidden" />`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to download the image on `click`. To achieve this you should use an `<a />` tag. Try the following:

```
function save(){

    let a = document.createElement('a');

    a.download = '';

    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    a.click();
}
```

Now you can use the `save` function whenever you want, even `onclick`.

Comment: Be more specific please. What versions? It might not be the case :}

Comment: OK, you tell us which browser that code will work in :p

Comment: insted of <img src="" alt="My Logo"  /> i wsiah to save result in 
<img src="" alt="" class="image image--hidden" />